# Rad Studio 10.2.1 Memory Leaks Windows 10 store

Tags: windows, delphi, firemonkey

It's well know around the Delphi community that there are memory leaks in Rad Studio 10.2.1 FMX. I did find a workaround for it: [Workaround for fmx memory leaks](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/workaround-for-fmx-memory-leaks-on-windows-in-10-2-1)

I want to know some stuff about it.

1. Does this only affect FMX Windows?
2. Someone told me that if your app is on the windows store the memory leaks aren't a matter since windows store terminates them. Is this true? Here is his exact words:

> if you publish on Windows Store then it's not needed because all memory is automatically freed by the Store when an app is terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All memory is always released when you kill the Delphi process, on all targets (Win32/Win64 or Store), IIRC. Windows Store engine may kill by itself a process eating all memory.

Anyway, the linked blog article by Marco states that the leak is reported only due to unproper shutdown. It affects FMX Windows.

There is no FMX leak which may let your application memory consumption grow up to some GB. Only some minor leak reporting when you define

```
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;
```

So nothing to be afraid, here.